# 403 Forbidden - Unable to consume third part API from server

Tags: c#, .net-core, http-status-code-403, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an application developed using .net core 2.1, and this application is  trying to access a third part API using HttpClient resources. Everything works fine when I'm debugging the application on localhost, but after publish the app to staging server the requests made by server to our customer API always return 403(Forbidden) status code.

Looking for a solution, I've did this actions below:

• The customer API works when I request the methods directly on postman and everything worked fine.

• I've tried to upload my application to different server.

• Clear the request head, cookies and certificates.

• Check if my firewall rules are blocking theses requests

Talking our client API Administrator, we found a similar case that happened with java applications, and the solution, was register the Costumer API public certificate on server to be used by these requests. It's possible do the same resolution on .net? If this solution is not our case what more I can try?

Thank you all.

Comment: What is the tech stack , WPF -> WCF/WebAPI or ASP.Net etc... Because from the question it mostly looks like a permission issue. When you are debugging it is using your NT credentials but probably the Hosting application pool identity has a ISS or similar User that is used and not recognized by third party API.

Comment: @Viju it's a Web API built on .netcore v2.1

Comment: I would recommend looking at the User under which IIS Poll is running. From what i hear surely sounds like a User Identity / Permission issue. Try updating the IIS App Pool Identity with your credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, this API has open methods that we can access without any credentials, we're testing access this kind of methods